# Transform JSON to user readable text

Tags: javascript

I need help on transforming the JSON to an user readable text.

Sample JSON:

```
{
    "condition": "or",
    "rules": [{
            "field": "X",
            "operator": "IN",
            "value": ["A", "B"]
        },
        {
            "field": "Y",
            "operator": "IN",
            "value": ["C", "D"]
        },
        {
            "condition": "and",
            "rules": [{
                    "field": "X",
                    "operator": "IN",
                    "value": ["F", "G"]
                },
                {
                    "condition": "and",
                    "rules": [{
                        "field": "Z",
                        "operator": "IN",
                        "value": ["R", "S"]
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "field": "I",
            "operator": "IN",
            "value": ["D", "K"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
X in('A','B') OR Y in('C','D') OR ( X in('F','G') and ( Z in('R','S') ) ) OR I in('D','K')
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hard to help if you don't tell us where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please understand SO is not a free coding service. You have to make some attempt to solve the problem yourself. If you can't get it working, post what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looked like a fun challenge, so I did it and then accidentally pushed the submit button, so here it is. I'll leave it to the OP to research how it works.

```js
const data = { "condition": "or", "rules": [{ "field": "X", "operator": "IN", "value": ["A", "B"] }, { "field": "Y", "operator": "IN", "value": ["C", "D"] }, { "condition": "and", "rules": [{ "field": "X", "operator": "IN", "value": ["F", "G"] }, { "condition": "and", "rules": [{ "field": "Z", "operator": "IN", "value": ["R", "S"] }] } ] }, { "field": "I", "operator": "IN", "value": ["D", "K"] } ] };

const expect = "X in('A','B') OR Y in('C','D') OR ( X in('F','G') and ( Z in('R','S') ) ) OR I in('D','K')";

const utils = {
  quote(s) { return `'${s}'` },
  parse(obj) {
    return parsers[obj.condition || obj.operator](obj);
  }
};

const parsers = {
  or(obj) {
    return obj.rules.map(utils.parse).join(" OR ");
  },
  and(obj) {
    return `( ${obj.rules.map(utils.parse).join(" and ")} )`;
  },
  IN(obj) {
    return `${obj.field} in(${obj.value.map(utils.quote).join(",")})`;
  }
};

const result = utils.parse(data);

console.log(`match? ${result == expect}`);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getObjects(obj, key, val) {
        var objects = [];
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
            if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
                objects = objects.concat(this.getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
            } else
                if (i == key && obj[i] == val || i == key && val == '') { //
                    objects.push(obj);
                } else if (obj[i] == val && key == '') {
                    if (objects.lastIndexOf(obj) == -1) {
                        objects.push(obj);
                    }
                }
        }
        return objects;
    }
I was able to break JSON into separate objects but stuck on combining those objects with the conditional operator and also to preserve the hierarchy. Thank you doodle for your answer.
```